# Alpine Docker define specific python version (python3-3.8.7-r0:breaks: world[python3=3.6.9-r3])

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux

when I want to build my Alpine Docker I get an error when I define specific python version.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add build-base openldap-dev python2-dev 'python3=3.6.9-r3' 'python3-dev=3.6.9-r3'
RUN pip3 install python-ldap sqlalchemy requests
ADD ucs-root-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt && update-ca-certificates

COPY templates ./templates
COPY api.py filedb.py syncer.py ./

VOLUME [ "/db" ]
VOLUME [ "/conf/dovecot" ]
VOLUME [ "/conf/sogo" ]

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "syncer.py" ]
```

I get the following Error when I want to build my dockerfile:

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python3-3.8.7-r0:
    breaks: world[python3=3.6.9-r3]
    satisfies: python3-dev-3.8.7-r0[python3=3.8.7-r0]
  python3-dev-3.8.7-r0:
    breaks: world[python3-dev=3.6.9-r3]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache add build-base openldap-dev python2-dev 'python3=3.6.9-r3' 'python3-dev=3.6.9-r3'' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error from apk is since that specific Python 3 version is not found in the Alpine repositories.

`python3=3.6.9-r3` currently only lives in the Alpine 3.9 `main` repository:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86/python3

The `python:3-alpine` image seems to be based on Alpine 3.13, the latest. Therefore, the package for 3.6.9  is not to be found.
For installing that specific version, you have to tell `apk` to use that 3.9 repository (if you're not on Alpine 3.9):

```
apk add python3-dev=3.6.9-r3 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main
```

However, there's a catch: `python3-dev=3.6.9-r3` is compatible with Alpine 3.9, and will not mix well with later Alpine versions. For example:

```
  gdbm-1.19-r0:
    conflicts: gdbm-1.13-r1
               gdbm-1.13-r1[so:libgdbm_compat.so.4=4.0.0]
    satisfies: python3-3.6.9-r3[so:libgdbm_compat.so.4]
               libsasl-2.1.27-r10[so:libgdbm.so.6]
               python2-2.7.18-r1[so:libgdbm_compat.so.4]
```

Therefore, if you're inclined to use Python `3.6.9` specifically, you'll have to run it on Alpine 3.9, which is quite old.

If you don't mind using an older Alpine version, simply replace the first line in your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
```